# Can we apply ACL in default route?

Tags: acl

I have default route setup as

```
ip route 0.0.0.0/0 172.16.15.2
```

where `172.16.15.2` is internet connected router with NAT.
Here is some snippet of the router configuration:

```
interface GigabitEthernet0/1.1
 encapsulation dot1q 10
 ip address 172.16.10.1 255.255.255.0 
# 
interface GigabitEthernet0/1.2
 encapsulation dot1q 20
 ip address 172.16.20.1 255.255.255.0
#
interface GigabitEthernet0/1.3
 encapsulation dot1q 15
 ip address 172.16.15.1 255.255.255.252
 ip access-group 101 out
#
access-list 101 deny ip 172.16.11.0 0.0.0.255 172.16.15.2 0.0.0.3 
access-list 101  permit ip any any 
 ip route 0.0.0.0/0 172.16.15.2
```

I want internet to be allowed only for `172.16.10.0`, but not for `172.16.11.0`. The ACL applied on outbound interface of `fa0/1.3` is not working. Is there any other solution that prevents traffic to be forwarded to `172.16.15.2` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`access-list 101 deny ip 172.16.11.0 0.0.0.255 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.255` should work - deny when source is 172.16.11.0/24 and destination is anything. Note that ACLs have an implied `deny ip any any` at the end.

If this is too restrictive - denies other private subnets as well - you need to allow those before:

```
100 permit ip 172.16.11.0 0.0.0.255 172.16.0.0 0.15.255.255
110 deny ip 172.16.11.0 0.0.0.255 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.255
9999 permit ip any any
```

Or more generally, permit all traffic within 172.16.0.0/12 but deny 172.16.11.0/24 traffic to elsewhere:

```
100 permit ip 172.16.0.0 0.15.255.255 172.16.0.0 0.15.255.255
110 deny ip 172.16.11.0 0.0.0.255 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.255
9999 permit ip any any
```

Comment: This solution helped me: `100 deny ip 172.16.11.0 0.0.0.255 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.255`  `100 permit ip any any` and `ip access-group 100 out` in interface fa0/1.3
`